# Set strongly typed view through Ajax or MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am new to MVC and we are building a MVC application having razor views and Web API controller for fetching data from Repository layer.

Now, we have a login screen and after successful authentication we want to redirect the user to Accounts page which is strongly typed. For authenticating credentials we make an Ajax call on button click and based on results, we display an error message or perform the redirection in Ajax’s success method.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/api/User/Authenticate',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (isValid) {
                if (isValid)
                    window.location.href = "/User/Account";
            },
            failure: OnFailure
        });
```

We are confused about the redirection and data fetching implementation. As mentioned, Account page is strongly typed view with 'UserAccount' entity. I want to populate this entity and then directly send it to Accounts page so that I can powerfully use the feature of Model binding.

We have found two approaches to do this:

1. Call the Web API controller inside MVC controller belonging to Accounts page.

   ```
    public ActionResult Account()
    {
       AccountsAPIController account = new AccountsAPIController();
       UserAccount userAccount = account.GetAccountsDetails(234);
       return View(userAccount);
    }
   ```
2. Fetch data on Account pages load and then manually assign each Entities property to respective controls. This works but then it overlooks the concept of strongly typed views.

   ```
    $.ajax({
             type: 'get',
             url: '/api/AccountsAPI/ GetAccountsDetails,
             datatype: 'json',
             data: {'userID': 234},
             contentType: 'application/json; ',
             success: function (data) {

                 // Assign data value to each and every control
                 $('#First_Name').val(data.First_Name);
                 $('#Phone_Number').val(data.Phone_Number);
                 // ..
             },
             failure: OnFailure
         });
   ```

Please suggest which method is correct or is there any standard approach we can go with.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I find myself referring back to this [article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460893/Unobtrusive-AJAX-Form-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC) many times (the article is too large to replicate here).

It shows you how to create a normal form on a page using `Html.BeginForm()`, then how to convert it to use `Ajax.BeginForm()`.  This allows you to submit a small portion of the page using AJAX, whilst being able to still use strongly-typed models, model binding and all the model validation attribute goodness of MVC (including all the `Html.TextBoxFor()`, `Html.ValidationMessageFor()` helpers etc.).